SPM: Automatic Demand state change to Approved on stakeholder approval
Currently, when a demand reaches the state 'Qualified', approvals are generated for multiple stakeholders in a related list on the demand form. When all the stakeholders approve the approvals, the demand field approval gets the value 'approved' and the demand automatically moves from the state 'Qualified' to the state 'Approved'. I have not been able to find the script/flow/workflow that makes this change
I would like to change this so that just a single approval is enough for the state to change to 'Approved'.
I wrote a business rule that checks for at least one approval on the 'sysapproval_approver' table, and then sets the 'State' field on the demand referenced on the 'sysapproval_approver' to 'Approved'. But this doesn’t work because the 'When to run' field references the “approval” field on the demand table and not the approvals table. Does anyone know how i can do this?
